# Redis Sentinel Readonly Slave with no Auth

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, redis-py

**Setup:** I have three machines with co-located Sentinel/Redis, exactly as in [example-2](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#example-2-basic-setup-with-three-boxes), configured with `sentinel auth-pass`, `masterauth`, `requirepass`. -- failover, read/write -- all works.

**Requirement:** I want to add in a Redis slave (4th instance of Redis) that does not require auth, but replicates from the main cluster.

**Issue:** I setup  exactly as in [the uncommon case where you need a slave that is accessible without authentication](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#sentinel-and-redis-authentication), ie, Master >> Slave,`replica-priority 0`.
When using redis-py client, I ask Sentinel for a slave to read from and this `no-auth-slave` is chosen, i receive error: `Client sent AUTH, but no password is set` and connection is aborted. I believe the client is just passing back the error from server.

**I've Tried:**

- Master  >>  Slave,`replica-priority 0`  >>  Slave,`replica-priority 0`. All clients, servers, sync work (because Sentinel doesn't know about this readonly slave) except I get `+fix-slave-config` entries every 10s in Sentinel log. Not sure if this is concerning??
- Setup as defined in "the uncommon case..." with Master >> (Slave,`replica-priority 0`) but client error, and unable to proceed with connection/request.

**Questions:**

- Is Master >> Slave >> Slave with Sentinel `+fix-slave-config` entries ok?
- Is `Client sent AUTH, but no password is set` a bug/feature?

I would definitely prefer to have all Redis slaves known by Sentinel for HA though, but doesn't work mixing auth/no-auth.

Redis 5.0.3, redis-py 3.2.0

Comment: this is very strange, why you remove the auth from 4th one

Comment: @c4f4t0r auth is to keep from accidental misuse/flush by other teams. additional node is for other teams -- all use on 'safe' LAN.

Comment: @Ok, I understand, remove it from all nodes :)